# Can I use same LDO for two outputs?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, linear-regulator

Can I use same LDO for two or three outputs? Given that the LDO provides enough needed current for three devices.

Comment: Sure you can... and this applies to virtually any voltage regulator even those that are not low-drop-out.

Comment: Remember to account for the power dissipation of the LDO, and add heat sinks if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If the regulator provides enough current, then yes, it is possible to power multiple devices (or loads) from it.

Let's assume you have a maximum of 10A available:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2dv5y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, it will easily power 3 separate loads. If the total added up to more than 10A, then you have a problem. Otherwise, it'll be fine.

This is the same for any regulator. Any voltage supply, LDO, SMPS or whatever you want to use that provides a voltage can supply multiple loads as long as you don't go over the maximum.

Although saying that, it is always best to give yourself some headroom. If you have a 10A max, try not to go any higher than 9A for example, you will always get some unexpected resistances because the real world doesn't work in ideals.

Comment: Also, it may be best to separate "sensitive" circuits. For example, if the 500mA load were a microcontroller and the 5A load was a switched motor, switching on and off the motor would create a voltage spike which could upset or even damage the microcontroller. Solution: put the microcontroller on it's own LDO.

Comment: @rdtsc good point